# Validate a field from a directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to wrap an input and some markup into an AngularJS directive.

However the fields are supposedly always validated which they shouldn't be.

Please check out my example @ http://plnkr.co/edit/TivmuqQI4Y5K56gwcadW

here is the code for those who do not wish to look at Plunker

my directive

```
app.directive('myInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^ngModel',
    templateUrl: 'form_control.html',
    scope: {
      label: '@',
      placeholder: '@',
      name: '@',
      form: '=',
      ngModel: '=ngModel'
    },
  }
});
```

this is my template

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': form.{{name}}.$invalid && form.{{name}}.$dirty, 'has-success': form.{{name}}.$valid }">
<label for="{{name}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{label}}</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="{{type}}" class="form-control col-sm-10" id="{{name}}" name="{{name}}" ng-model="ngModel" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-maxlength="10" ng-required="true">
</div>
</div>
```

and this is in my index.html

```
<my-input ng-model="website.url" name="url" label="URL" placeholder="http://example.com" form="form"></my-input>
```

Even though the input inside the template is required, the field is validated, which it shouldn't be if it's empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your plunker, one field is green and one is red. You want both to be green upon load? then show invalid when? when form is submitted? how does the form know when to validate inputs? any required field is invalid upon DOM load.

Answer (score 0):

Required fields are immediately invalid on DOM load, as they are not valid until they have a value.

Also, in your plunker the top input is green, with an illusion of valid while the lower input is red showing invalid as it should.

You can't do this...

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': form.{{name}}.$invalid && form.{{name}}.$dirty, 'has-success': form.{{name}}.$valid }">
```

The issue is with the form name field. When you do this...

```
<input type="{{type}}" class="form-control col-sm-10" id="{{name}}" name="{{name}}" ng-model="ngModel" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-maxlength="10" ng-required="true">
```

name="{{name}} will actually compile to name: {{name}} in the form object. exmaple:

```
{{name}}: Constructor$dirty: false
          $error: Object
          $formatters: Array[1]
          $invalid: true
          $isEmpty: function (value) {
            $modelValue: undefined
            $name: "{{name}}"
            $parsers: Array[1]...
```

This was taken from your plunker. Play around with console.log($scope.form) and look at the object.
under $error you will find that there are two inputs THIS form references, and neither of them are the expected input named 'url', they are in fact the 'title' input and your directive input '{{name}}' as seen here...

```
form: Constructor
  $addControl: function (control) {
    $dirty: false
    $error: Object...
      $name: "title"...
      $name: "{{name}}"
```

Here is a forked plunker where I have already set up to console.log the form

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NkiBQHXpqtCxExyzaQAF?p=preview)

This shows that the form has no idea about any 'url' input. To get around this, you can write a custom directive for the input name field. Or just use the one I wrote below.

```
app.directive('myName', function(){

  var myNameError = "myName directive error: "

  return {
    restrict:'A', // Declares an Attributes Directive.
    require: 'ngModel', // ngModelController.

    link: function( scope, elem, attrs, ngModel ){
      if( !ngModel ){ return } // if no ngModel exists for this element

      checkInputFormat(attrs); // check myName input for proper formatting.

      var inputName = attrs.myName.match('^\\w+').pop(); // match upto '/'
      assignInputNameToInputModel(inputName, ngModel);

      var formName = attrs.myName.match('\\w+$').pop(); // match after '/'
      findForm(formName, ngModel, scope);
    } // end link
  } // end return

  function checkInputFormat(attrs){
    if( !/\w\/\w/.test(attrs.myName )){ // should be in format "wordcharacters/wordcharacters"
      throw myNameError + "Formatting should be \"inputName/formName\" but is " + attrs.myName
    }
  }

  function assignInputNameToInputModel(inputName, ngModel){
    ngModel.$name = inputName // adds string to ngModel.$name variable.
  }

  function addInputNameToForm(formName, ngModel, scope){
    scope[formName][ngModel.$name] = ngModel; return // add input name and input object.
  }

  function findForm(formName, ngModel, scope){
    if( !scope ){ // ran out of scope before finding scope[formName]
      throw myNameError + "<Form name=" + formName + "'> element could not be found."
    }
    if( formName in scope){ // found scope[formName]
      addInputNameToForm(formName, ngModel, scope)
      return
    }
    findForm(formName, ngModel, scope.$parent) // recursively search through $parent scopes
  }
});

// DIRECTIVE NOTES:
// This directive is used by simply including the following HTML element:
// <input my-name="email/profileForm">.
// In the example above, the input name is "email" and the form name
// that this input would be attached to would be named "profileForm"
// Like this...
// <form name="profileForm">
//   <input my-name="email/profileForm">
// </form>
// Notice this "/" dividing the input name from the form name.  This directive uses the '/'
// to separate the input name from the form name.
// Although it has not been tested yet, this directive should work with multi nested forms
// as well, as the recursive search only looks for the form name that was passed in, inwhich
// to bind the ngModel to.
// In this example, other form names would be skipped.
// <form name="profileForm">
//   <form name="miniFormOne">
//      <form name="miniFormTwo">
//        <input my-name="email/profileForm">
//      </form>
//   </form>
// </form>
// The above example may not be the best behavior, but was just added as an example.
```

With this directive, you could use your nested directive input like this

```
<input type="{{type}}" class="form-control col-sm-10" id="{{name}}" my-name="{{ variableName  + '/' + yourformnamevariable  }}" ng-model="ngModel" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-maxlength="10" ng-required="true">
```

The myName directive will get this: "url/form" in your case, then it will add the $name variable which will be 'url' to the ngModel for THAT input, as well as search up scope for the form named "form" and attach the ndModel to THAT form. The directive uses the '/' to separate names. The search is recursive and will travel until it finds the form name or error out with a message.

Of course when you create dynamic input names, how are you to call out

formName.dynamicInputName.$valid? as you don't know what the dynamic input names ARE!!!

So using form.{{name}}.$invalid && form.{{name}}.$dirty doesn't work unless you do this...

```
form.$valid && form.$dirty
```

But that won't work for each individual input. You can figure out your own way to do that...

I use another directive inside the input

Then in my-errors I just listen to the ngModel like after requiring ngModel, you can now call ngModel.$invalid then set a variable to change the CSS. If I get some time, I'll make a jsFiddle and link it here at the bottom. However, you can just use the class input.ng-invalid { border-color: red; } and the inputs will be red until they are valid.

If this doesn't clear things up, ask some more questions... We'll get it.

Hope this helpy's